# Grails : Difference between \${} and ${}

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp

Can someone tell me the difference between :

```
<g:if test="${foo.bar}">
```

and

```
<g:if test="\${foo.bar}">
```

A real exemple of the use of "\" before the "$" is :

```
<g:if test="\${flash.message}">
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\${...}` will put a literal dollar-brace into the output rather than evaluating the contents as an expression. I rarely have need to use this in a normal GSP but it's very common in scaffolding templates where the template engine uses the same `${}` syntax for its own generation-time expressions as the generated GSP uses at runtime - so you need `\${}` in the scaffolding template to generate expressions in the GSP which will then be evaluated for real at runtime when the page is rendered.

Comment: Thank you ! During my search I found this in the "Getting Started With Grails Second Edition" from Scott Davis & Jason Rudolph : "In <g:if test="\${session?.user?.admin}">, the backslash in front of the dollar sign tells Grails to execute this code at run-time. Other places, you’ll see code like var="${property Name}". In that instance, propertyName will be resolved when the template is generated."

Comment: @GuillaumeM yes, that's definitely talking about scaffolding templates rather than "normal" GSPs.

Answer (score 0):

This http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-do-you-avoid-interpolation-of-an-html-attribute-in-GSP-to-print-a-literal-with-td1353164.html helped to me to avoid interpolation of dollar sign. \$ doesn't work for me.